# Javascript object is overwriting itself

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to parse some data I extract from a google sheets into a javascript object to create some sitelink extensions within google apps scripts. My code for parsing the data is:

```
function parseData(sheetData)
{
  var parsedData = {};
  var header = sheetData.shift()
  for(lineIndex in sheetData)
  {
    var accountID = sheetData[lineIndex][0]
    var campaignName = sheetData[lineIndex][1]
    var description1 = sheetData[lineIndex][2]
    var description2 = sheetData[lineIndex][3]
    var url = sheetData[lineIndex][4]
    
    if(!(accountID in Object.keys(parsedData)))
    {
      parsedData[accountID] = {}
    }
    if(!(campaignName in Object.keys(parsedData[accountID])))
    {
      var tempObject = {}
      parsedData[accountID][campaignName] = tempObject
      for(columnIndex in sheetData[lineIndex])
      {
        //parsedData[accountID][campaignName][header[columnIndex]] = sheetData[lineIndex][columnIndex]
        tempObject[header[columnIndex]] = sheetData[lineIndex][columnIndex]
      }
      parsedData[accountID][campaignName] = tempObject
    }
  }
  return parsedData
}
```

I'm doing this so I can retrieve information by accountID and campaignName in the next steps.

But every time it creates the "campaignName" object it ends upd overwriting itself and only saves the last campaignName object, only one per accountID object.

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Edit:
I was expecting to get an object in the following shape:

```
{{111-111-2222=
    {campaignName1=
        {description1=best prices available, 
        url=https://exampleurl.com},
    {campaignName2=
        {description1=Em até 12x sem Juros, 
        url=https://exampleurl.com}
},
{111-111-3333=
    {campaignName1=
        {description1=best prices available, 
        url=https://exampleurl.com},
    {campaignName2=
        {description1=Em até 12x sem Juros, 
        url=https://exampleurl.com}
}}
```

So, when I execute my code, I can access data by:

```
var currentAccountID = AdsApp.currentAccount().getCustomerId();
  var campaignNames = Object.keys(sitelinkData[currentAccountID])
  
  var campaigns = AdsApp.campaigns()
                        .withCondition("CampaignStatus='ENABLED'")
                        .get()
  while(campaigns.hasNext())
  {
    var campaign = campaigns.next()
    var campaignName = campaign.getName()
    var description1 = parsedData[currentAccountID][campaignName]["Description1"]
}
}
```

Comment: *But every time it creates the "campaignName" object it ends upd overwriting itself and only saves the last campaignName object, only one per accountID object.* - Can you also give an example of what ends up in `parsedData` and what you want using mock `accountId` and `campaignName`?

Comment: I edited my code with the following steps to access data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that might work. It's tough to test because there's no data. But the problem you have, I think, is that you're assigning `parsedData[accountID][campaignName] = tempObject` rather than appending `tempObject` to the existing `parsedData[accountID][campaignName]`

```
function parseData(sheetData)
{
  var parsedData = {};
  var header = sheetData.shift()
  for(lineIndex in sheetData)
  {
    var accountID = sheetData[lineIndex][0]
    var campaignName = sheetData[lineIndex][1]
    var description1 = sheetData[lineIndex][2]
    var description2 = sheetData[lineIndex][3]
    var url = sheetData[lineIndex][4]
    
    
    if(!parsedData[accountId])
    {
      parsedData[accountID] = []
    }
    if(!parsedData[accountID][campaignName])
    {
      parsedData[accountID][campaignName] = {} // <= instantiate here
    }
    for(columnIndex in sheetData[lineIndex])
    {
      parsedData[accountID][campaignName][header[columnIndex]] = sheetData[lineIndex][columnIndex]
    }
  }
  return parsedData
}
```

Comment: I tried this before (you can see by the commented part) and not worked either :/

Comment: Did you try with the instantiation as I put it in my code?

Comment: Yes, still got only one campaignName per accountID

Comment: I've made an edit to remove the `in Object.keys` checks, which I think are probably the problem. `Object.keys` returns an array, and `in` looks at indices not values.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you so much!

Comment: In first `if` you use `accountId` instead of `accountID`. It shouldn't work

Comment: Why did you change `parsedData[accountID] = {}` (as it was in original) to `parsedData[accountID] = []` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've added some data, run your script as is, and get some output. Now can you show us what do you want to change in this output?

```js
var data = [
    ["accountID", "campaignName", "description1", "description2", "url"],
    ["id1", "company name 1", "info 1", "info 1", "url1"],
    ["id2", "company name 2", "info 2", "info 2", "url2"],
    ["id3", "company name 3", "info 3", "info 3", "url3"]
];


function parseData(sheetData)
{
  var parsedData = {};
  var header = sheetData.shift()
  for(lineIndex in sheetData)
  {
    var accountID = sheetData[lineIndex][0]
    var campaignName = sheetData[lineIndex][1]
    var description1 = sheetData[lineIndex][2]
    var description2 = sheetData[lineIndex][3]
    var url = sheetData[lineIndex][4]

    if(!(accountID in Object.keys(parsedData)))
    {
      parsedData[accountID] = {}
    }
    if(!(campaignName in Object.keys(parsedData[accountID])))
    {
      var tempObject = {}
      parsedData[accountID][campaignName] = tempObject
      for(columnIndex in sheetData[lineIndex])
      {
        //parsedData[accountID][campaignName][header[columnIndex]] = sheetData[lineIndex][columnIndex]
        tempObject[header[columnIndex]] = sheetData[lineIndex][columnIndex]
      }
      parsedData[accountID][campaignName] = tempObject
    }
  }
  return parsedData
}

console.log(parseData(data));
```

Output:

```
{
  id1: {
    'company name 1': {
      accountID: 'id1',
      campaignName: 'company name 1',
      description1: 'info 1',
      description2: 'info 1',
      url: 'url1'
    }
  },
  id2: {
    'company name 2': {
      accountID: 'id2',
      campaignName: 'company name 2',
      description1: 'info 2',
      description2: 'info 2',
      url: 'url2'
    }
  },
  id3: {
    'company name 3': {
      accountID: 'id3',
      campaignName: 'company name 3',
      description1: 'info 3',
      description2: 'info 3',
      url: 'url3'
    }
  }
}
```

I've took the snipped from the accepted answer (fixed one typo) and run it with the same date. Here is the output:

```
{
  id1: [
    'company name 1': {
      accountID: 'id1',
      campaignName: 'company name 1',
      description1: 'info 1',
      description2: 'info 1',
      url: 'url1'
    }
  ],
  id2: [
    'company name 2': {
      accountID: 'id2',
      campaignName: 'company name 2',
      description1: 'info 2',
      description2: 'info 2',
      url: 'url2'
    }
  ],
  id3: [
    'company name 3': {
      accountID: 'id3',
      campaignName: 'company name 3',
      description1: 'info 3',
      description2: 'info 3',
      url: 'url3'
    }
  ]
}
```

I see no differences except `{}` become `[]` (due another bug or intentional change in accepted answer).

So, where was a problem?

---

As far as I can tell from OP there should be this:

```js
var data = [
  ["accountID", "CampaignName", "Description1", "Description2", "url"],
  ["id1", "company 1", "description company 1", "description2 company 1", "url 1"],
  ["id2", "company 2", "description company 2", "description2 company 2", "url 2"],
  ["id3", "company 3", "description company 3", "description2 company 3", "url 3"]
];

function parseData(sheetData) {

  var header = sheetData.shift();
  var companies = {}

  for (var row in sheetData) {
    var campaignName = sheetData[row][1];
    companies[campaignName] = {};
    companies[campaignName][header[2]] = sheetData[row][2]; // description1
    companies[campaignName][header[4]] = sheetData[row][4]; // url
    // etc for any column in your table
  }

  var parsedData = {}
  sheetData.forEach(r => parsedData[r[0]] = companies);
  return parsedData;
}

var parsedData = parseData(data);
var id_company_description = parsedData["id1"]["company 2"]["Description1"];

console.log(parsedData); // see output
console.log(id_company_description); // "description company 2"
```

Output:

```
{
  id1: {
    'company 1': { Description1: 'description company 1', url: 'url 1' },
    'company 2': { Description1: 'description company 2', url: 'url 2' },
    'company 3': { Description1: 'description company 3', url: 'url 3' }
  },
  id2: {
    'company 1': { Description1: 'description company 1', url: 'url 1' },
    'company 2': { Description1: 'description company 2', url: 'url 2' },
    'company 3': { Description1: 'description company 3', url: 'url 3' }
  },
  id3: {
    'company 1': { Description1: 'description company 1', url: 'url 1' },
    'company 2': { Description1: 'description company 2', url: 'url 2' },
    'company 3': { Description1: 'description company 3', url: 'url 3' }
  }
}

description company 2
```